# How do i get certain elements using xpath, ie fb, twitter and google+(elements 1,2 and 4) elements using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

![How do i get certain elements using xpath][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgwZX.jpg ""

Comment: What elements? can you post any html snippet?

Comment: hai , have shared the html above in a link

Answer (score 0):

You can write an xpath like:

`//a[contains(@href, 'facebook') or contains(@href, 'twitter') or contains(@href, 'google')]`

If you need to narrow the section you can also add to be in the `socials` div:

`//div[@class='socials']//a[contains(@href, 'facebook') or contains(@href, 'twitter') or contains(@href, 'google')]`

If you only need one of them then use something like:

`//div[@class='socials']//a[contains(@href, 'facebook')]`

I see that you also have classes for each so you can also use something like:
`//div[@class='socials']//a[@class='fb']` 
or 
`//div[@class='socials']//a[@class='fb' or @class='twitter' or @class='google']`